# slideshow on ipad

Tags: ipad, slideshow

I want to set up an ipad so that it just sits there looping through an album of photos. It should never shut off. It should never stop, unless someone hits the 'home' button.

A certain amount of googling leads me to be very pessimistic about this.

Can anyone offer a recipe?

Comment: something like screen-sawer slide show ?

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: http://www.imore.com/how-make-photo-slideshow-your-iphone-or-ipad

Comment: Broken in several well-documented ways, especially on iOS8.

Comment: you are on iso8, could have assumed but one newer knows if not stated.